# Ingress get 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

I have several Ingress on my cluster and they're working fine.
Till the day one of them got 502 Bad Gateway. I have re-checked the pod, service and all of them work fine. I'm really sure that my Ingress configuration is correct 'cause it has been worked for a while.

I'm using AKS, so I checked the cluster insight and got the report that I got `Disk IOPs Throttling` issue, please see below. I'm not sure that this issue is the cause of the problem above or not but it is the highest possibility.

[image]

Does anyone encounter this case? Or have any idea about this? I'm in stuck for a while on this issue.
Thank you!

Comment: Is it happening to a single pod only? can you try to use `port forwarding`?

Comment: Yes. I tried using port forwarding for pod and service as well, they work. @AmitBaranes

Comment: Could you share your service and ingress definition ?